# Abrir maps generando ruta

Tags: android, google-maps

Buenas, estoy desarrollando una app android, en ella tengo una instancia de `google maps` donde dibujo varios marcadores.

Si solo pinto uno, el mapa me muestra las herramientas donde puedo darle y que me abra la aplicación de mapas con la ruta entre mi posición y el marcador que he pulsado, pero al pintar varios marcadores esta opción se quita, me gustaría llamar a esa función desde otro fragment pasandole la posición hasta donde quiero que genere la ruta. ¿Es posible hacer esto? ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Cargo el mapa:

```
    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    googleMap = map;
    googleMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    //googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false); //desactiva la opción de abrir google maps para ir al marcador

    CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(l)   //Centramos el mapa en Madrid
            .zoom(12)         //Establecemos el zoom en 19
            .bearing(0)      //Establecemos la orientación con el noreste arriba
            .tilt(70)         //Bajamos el punto de vista de la cámara 70 grados
            .build();

    CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(l.latitude, l.longitude))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))

    );
    for(int i=0;i<centros.size();i++){
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(centros.get(i).getLat(),centros.get(i).getLon())).title(centros.get(i).getNombre())
                .snippet(centros.get(i).getDire()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
        );
    }

    googleMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);



    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "id: "+marker.getId(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            CentroAcciones fragmentCentro = new CentroAcciones();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragmentCentro).commit();

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Centro Acciones

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(centroacciones, container, false);
    //TODO: obtiene null en las referencias a los botones

    llamar=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.llamar);
    llamar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Boton llamar",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                //TODO: obtener el tlf del centro que recibe como parámetro
                String phone="1234567890";
                Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));  //String phone
                startActivity(call);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Log.e("Excepción", e+"");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No se encontró aplicación para llamar.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    llegar=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.llegar);
    llegar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Boton llegar",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    solicitar=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.solicitud);
    solicitar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            centrosolicitar =new CentroSolicitar();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, centrosolicitar).commit();
        }

    });

    return rootView;
}
```

en este on create tengo tres opciones, llamar, ruta y solicitar, llamar me lanza el dialer con el telefono, solicitar me lanza otro fragment con sus acciones y mi pregunta va enfocada a ruta, ya que es donde me gustaría lanzar google maps con la ruta desde mi posición hasta la longitud-latitud de ese centro.

Gracias

Comment: comenta la parte de tu algoritmo de la que hablas, para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

Los pasos:

- Puedes trazar la ruta haciendo una petición a la [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)
- Decodifica el string usando la librería [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) con el metodo `PolyUtil.decode`.
- Añda los puntos decodificados al mapa:

  ```
  List<LatLng> decodedPoints = PolyUtil.decode(polylineString);
  PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
  options.width(6);
  options.color(Color.RED);
  options.addAll(decodedPoints);

  map.addPolyline(options);
  ```

Pero si lo que quieres es ahorrar tiempo puedes utilizar esta librería hecha por [akexorcist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554078/is-there-a-way-to-show-road-directions-in-google-map-api-v2/15053948#15053948). El único problema con esta librería es que utiliza `HtttpClient`, que es un método deprecado. Eso se soluciona cambiando un poco el código, sustituyendo el código de la clase `Navigator` con lo siguiente:
:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class Navigator {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Context context;
    private LatLng startPosition, endPosition;
    private String mode;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private Directions directions;
    private int pathColor = Color.BLUE;
    private int pathBorderColor = Color.BLACK;
    private int secondPath = Color.CYAN;
    private int thirdPath = Color.RED;
    private float pathWidth = 14;
    private OnPathSetListener listener;
    private boolean alternatives = false;
    private long arrivalTime;
    private String avoid;
    private ArrayList<Polyline> lines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();

    public Navigator(GoogleMap map, LatLng startLocation, LatLng endLocation){
        this.startPosition = startLocation;
        this.endPosition = endLocation;
        this.map = map;
    }

    public interface OnPathSetListener{
        public void onPathSetListener(Directions directions);
    }

    public void setOnPathSetListener(OnPathSetListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the starting location for the directions 
     */
    public LatLng getStartPoint(){
        return startPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the end location for the directions 
     * 
     */
    public LatLng getEndPoint(){
        return endPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Get's driving directions from the starting location to the ending location
     * 
     * @param showDialog 
     *  Set to true if you want to show a ProgressDialog while retrieving directions
     *  @param findAlternatives
     *  give alternative routes to the destination
     *  
     */
    public void findDirections(boolean findAlternatives){
        this.alternatives = findAlternatives;
        new PathCreator().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the type of direction you want (driving,walking,biking or mass transit). This MUST be called before getting the directions
     * If using "transit" mode you must provide an arrival time
     * 
     * @param mode
     * The type of directions you want (driving,walking,biking or mass transit)
     * @param arrivalTime
     * If selected mode it "transit" you must provide and arrival time (milliseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC). If arrival time is not given
     * the current time is given and may return unexpected results.
     */
    public void setMode(int mode, long arrivalTime,int avoid){
        switch(mode){

        case 0:
            this.mode = "driving";
            break;
        case 1:
            this.mode = "transit";
            this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
            break;
        case 2:
            this.mode = "bicycling";
            break;
        case 3:
            this.mode = "walking";
            break;
        default:
            this.mode = "driving";
            break;
        }

        switch(avoid){
        case 0:
            this.avoid = "tolls";
            break;
        case 1:
            this.avoid = "highways";
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get all direction information
     * @return
     */
    public Directions getDirections(){
        return directions;
    }

    /**
     * Change the color of the path line, must be called before calling findDirections().
     * @param firstPath
     * Color of the first line, default color is blue.
     * @param secondPath
     * Color of the second line, default color is cyan
     * @param thirdPath
     * Color of the third line, default color is red
     * 
     */
    public void setPathColor(int firstPath,int secondPath, int thirdPath){
        pathColor = firstPath;
    }

    public void setPathBorderColor(int firstPath,int secondPath, int thirdPath){
        pathBorderColor = firstPath;
    }

    /**
     * Change the width of the path line
     * @param width
     * Width of the line, default width is 3
     */
    public void setPathLineWidth(float width){
        pathWidth = width;
    }

    private Polyline showPath(Route route,int color){
        return map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(route.getPath()).color(color).width(pathWidth));
    }

    private Polyline showBorderPath(Route route, int color){
        return map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(route.getPath()).color(color).width(pathWidth + 10));
    }

    public ArrayList<Polyline> getPathLines(){
        return lines;
    }

    private class PathCreator extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Directions>{

        @Override
        protected Directions doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if(mode == null){
                mode = "driving";
            }

                String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"
                        + "origin=" + startPosition.latitude + "," + startPosition.longitude
                        + "&destination=" + endPosition.latitude + "," + endPosition.longitude
                        + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode="+mode+"&alternatives="+String.valueOf(alternatives)+"&key=AIzaSyByacMXwL8ItVkRTQqoKiWroAUg2xeNs34";

                if(mode.equals("transit")){
                    if(arrivalTime > 0){
                        url += url + "&arrival_time="+arrivalTime;
                    }else{
                        url += url + "&departure_time="+System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                }

                if(avoid != null){
                    url += url+"&avoid="+avoid;
                }

                try {
/*
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);

                    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){

                        String s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                        return new Directions(s);
                    }
                    return null;
*/

                    URL urlDef = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlDef.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    // para activar el metodo post
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    String line;
                    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                        response.append('\r');
                    }
                    rd.close();
                    String s = response.toString();
                    return new Directions(s);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Directions directions){

            if(directions != null){
                Navigator.this.directions = directions;
                for(int i=0; i<directions.getRoutes().size(); i++){
                    Route r = directions.getRoutes().get(i);
                    if(i == 0){
                        lines.add(showBorderPath(r,pathBorderColor));
                        lines.add(showPath(r,pathColor));
                    }else if(i == 1){
                        lines.add(showBorderPath(r,pathBorderColor));
                        lines.add(showPath(r,secondPath));
                    }else if(i == 3){
                        lines.add(showBorderPath(r,pathBorderColor));
                        lines.add(showPath(r,thirdPath));
                    }
                }

                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onPathSetListener(directions);
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Y en tu código del mapa(supongamos que se muestra al presionar un icono del menú):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.trying)
    {
        // caminando
        LatLng inicioR =  new LatLng(19.0436, -98.1981);
        LatLng finalR =  new LatLng(19.0500, -98.1981);
        Navigator nav = new Navigator(map,inicioR,finalR);
        nav.findDirections(false);
        // por efecto es manejando, ponemos la config para ir caminando
        nav.setMode(3,0,2);
        nav.setPathLineWidth(2); // aunque es 1, por defecto es 10+1
        nav.setPathBorderColor(Color.RED, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    if ( id == R.id.driving )
    {
        // manejando
        LatLng inicioR =  new LatLng(19.0436, -98.1981);
        LatLng finalR =  new LatLng(19.0500, -98.1981);
        Navigator nav = new Navigator(map,inicioR,finalR);
        nav.findDirections(false);
        // por efecto es manejando, aun si ponemos la config
        nav.setMode(0,0,2);
        nav.setPathLineWidth(2); // aunque es 1, por defecto es 10+1
        nav.setPathBorderColor(Color.GREEN, 0, 0);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Actualización: Al parecer la nueva versión de la librería ya cuenta con nuevas implementaciones con librerías para nuevas versiones de android, por lo que la modificación de la librería `navigator` está de sobra.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que utilizar `Polyline`

```
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(tu_latitud, tu_longitud), new LatLng(destino.latitude, destino.longitude))
            .width(4)
            .color(Color.GREEN));
```

**EDICION**

Si lo que quieres es abrir el mapa nativo directamente

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+destino.latitud+","+destino.longitud+"&mode=d");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Donde mode =

- d = auto
- w = a pie
- b = bicicleta

Comment: si, si quiero pintar una linea recta entre los dos puntos, pero no es mi intención, pretendo que me abra la aplicación de mapas con la ruta a seguir (por las calles) o bien alguna librería que me calculen la ruta

Comment: Entiendo, voy a editar

Comment: @RubenManzano edite, espero haber entendido que quieres ver en el mapa nativo la ruta que deseas

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, es justo lo que quería, aunque voy a echarle también un vistazo a la respuesta de @Rene Limon que puede ser que quede mejor dibujando directamente en el mapa, muchas gracias

Comment: @RubenManzano exacto!, cualquier cosa me comentas!